# extjs 4 - how to add button into panel header?

Tags: extjs

I have:

```
new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Header',                     
    hideCollapseTool: true,
    collapsible: true,
    collapsed: true,
    renderTo: 'mywrap',
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto',
    ...
}
```

How can I replace header one button the entire width/height with hover and ▲ Header ▼ instead of title?

as_is-as_to_be

[image: as_is-as_to_be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want to achieve you can do something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    border: true,
    bodyStyle: {
        padding: '10px'
    },
    collapsible: true,
    hideCollapseTool: true,
    html: 'Some data',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: '▲ Header ▼',
    titleAlign: 'center',
    titleCollapse: true
});
```

Check this [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17po).

If you still want to add button with height / width 100% you can do something like this:

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    ...
    title: '<button id="myButton" style="...">My header button</button>'
    ...
});
```

*(do not forget to remove panel header padding)*

and add handler to it via ExtJS, like this

```
// Get Ext.dom.Element via Ext.dom.Element.get() method
Ext.get('myButton').on('click', function() {
    if(myPanel.getCollapsed())
        myPanel.expand();
    else
        myPanel.collapse();
});
```

or JS, like this

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(myPanel.getCollapsed())
        myPanel.expand();
    else
        myPanel.collapse();
});
```

Check this [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17uf).

If you want to add some buttons to your header you can also use [`Ext.panel.Panel.tools`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tools) config.

*And ofcourse you can always overrite [`Ext.panel.Header`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Header).*

Comment: Thanks a lot! About "...and add handler to it via pure JS or ExtJS..." - could you give any example? I have id of Panel as 'panelId' and id of Button as 'btnId' - how I can use it? 
In my case call 'panel.header.el.on' in render (listeners) isn't work, do you know why?